# Grouping tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a view where I can see the renters names and how many times they have visited from the transactions table. In the first example I keep getting a error "subquery returns more than 1 row". The second example gives me the renters id and the times visited.

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name,
        (SELECT COUNT(renter_id)
         FROM transactions
         GROUP BY renter_id
        ) AS visited
 FROM renters
 WHERE renter_id IN (SELECT renter_id
                     FROM transactions
                     GROUP BY renter_id
                     having COUNT(renter_id) > 2
                    );


SELECT renter_id, COUNT(renter_id) AS visited
FROM transactions
GROUP BY renter_id
having COUNT(renter_id) > 2;
```

Comment: select first_name, last_name, COUNT(transactions.renter_id) FROM renters inner join  transactions on renters.renter_id= transactions.renter_id group by renter_id having COUNT(transactions.renter_id) > 2);

Comment: try the above query.

Comment: Column 'renter_id' in group statement is ambiguous

Comment: but you want to renter_id based count right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `JOIN`.  The query looks like this:

```
SELECT r.first_name, r.last_name, COUNT(*) AS num_visits
FROM transactions t JOIN
     renters r
     ON t.renter_id = r.renter_id
GROUP BY r.first_name, r.last_name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```